# Contract returns a hex value when a string is expected

Tags: solidity, erc-20, javascript, testing

I'm working with an ERC20 token and when I instantiate a new instance of it and try to receive its symbol in my tests, I receive a hex representation of the string.

```
const contract = await ERC20.new("DAI")
const contractSymbol = await contract.symbol.call()
```

The relevant code for the ERC20 token is the following

```
bytes32 public symbol;

constructor(bytes32 symbol_) public {
    symbol = symbol_;
}
```

When I log out `contractSymbol` I get the following instead of "DAI"

```
0x4441490000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Any explanations and suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: Someone correct me if I'm wrong (this is just an observation), the reason you are seeing it like that is because the EVM is big-endian (I think that's the proper way to say that). And that's why you're seeing the most significant bytes from left to right. As for why you are receiving a hex representation, what happens when you change `bytes32 public symbol;` to `string public symbol;` I'm assuming this has something to do with how web3 spits back the data to you. Because it is the correct value, nonetheless.

Comment: changing it to `string` works too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable is a bytes32. You need to convert it in a string.

Use `web3.utils.toAscii(val)` to do the convertion.
You can also use an online converter like [this one](http://string-functions.com/hex-string.aspx) (but remove the `0x` prefix).